# Why does my C# code call to RichTextBox.AppendText() not process \r\n consistently?

Tags: c#

I am processing received serial strings in my C# application (running on Windows 10).  I have a `RichTextBox` holding the data received from my device.  Using `AppendText()` works most of the time but sometimes the `\r\n` is ignored.  The code that puts the text string into the text box is:

```
// Put the data on the received data window
this.rtbIncoming.AppendText(text);
```

where `rtbIncoming` is defined as:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox rtbIncoming;
```

Most of the time I get the expected results of the `\r\n` causing the `RichTextBox` to place the following data at the beginning of the next line but sometimes it ignores the `\r\n` string.

You can see below where the first `\r\n`  is ignored but the one before the "OK" works as expected.

[image: Screen capture from Visual Studio debugger]

The output in the RichTextBox is:

[image: Output in RichTextBox]

Note: I ran the test twice so the result could be seen for the first run and the value of the string "text" inspected during the second run.  Notice how the `\r\r\n` at the beginning of the string is ignored and the +UMLA is placed right after the 1 of the command but the `\r\n` before the "OK" makes the "OK" text show up on the next line.

Is this expected behavior?  Most of the time it works and I haven't figured out what makes it not work.

Comment: Have you tested the hypothesis that `\r` not paired with `\n` is the problem?  `\r\r\n` has one paired `\r\n` but also has one standalone `\r`.

Comment: Looks like that was the issue.  I added `text = text.Replace("\r\r", "\r");` before my `this.rtbIncoming.AppendText(text);` and the problem went away.  If you add this hypothesis as an answer I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments, [Ben Voight notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68657973/why-does-my-c-sharp-code-call-to-richtextbox-appendtext-not-process-r-n-consi/69260698#comment121337286_68657973):

> Have you tested the hypothesis that `\r` not paired with `\n` is the problem? `\r\r\n` has one paired `\r\n` but also has one standalone `\r`.

Looks like that was the issue. I added:

```
text = text.Replace("\r\r", "\r");
```

before my

```
this.rtbIncoming.AppendText(text);
```

and the problem went away.